# How to restore SQL Server 2008 R2 backup to a LocalDb 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-restore, localdb

I have a backup of a database (`.bak`) created ​​in SQL Server 2008 R2.

To test some features, like to import this backup to LocalDB (2012).
When I click on Restore and select the database the following error occurs:

> *Property MasterDBLogPath is not available for Information 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Information'. This property may not exist for this object, or may not be retrievable due to insufficient access rights.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)*

Answer (score 8):

You need to add the following 3 registry keys (run/regedit):

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11E.LOCALDB\MSSQLServer\DefaultData,

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11E.LOCALDB\MSSQLServer\DefaultLog, 

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11E.LOCALDB\MSSQLServer\BackupDirectory
```

With an existing folder name as value (where you have write access), e.g. "C:\Databases".

Please have a look at the excellent walkthrough under http://www.roelvanlisdonk.nl/?p=2896 (which is where I have copied the answer from).